# What does Main.1 output file do in XCode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, build

I made a sample project called "Stack", but realized that i needed some more data structures, so i renamed everything - the project, made 2 new folders & their matching groups in XCode, modified the Target Build path to look for "Main/DataStructures-Prefix.pch" instead. But there's one file i don't understand -> earlier, i had gotten a "Stack.1" in my folder, so i just renamed it to "Main.1" and it doesn't *seem* to be affecting the build process, but i'm pretty skeptical. What does this "Main.1" do? is it the linked intermediate file like in C/C++?

here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: Why not double-click it to see what's inside, and update the screenshot to show its contents?

Comment: sorry, i just hadn't accept the answer since i wanted to get more views to confirm. but it seems that it's the man page. the content inside is just a bunch of unparsed arguments and it made no sense reading it from xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Main.1" is a template for creating a "man page" (i.e. an *on-line manual page*) for your program. You can verify that by calling

```
man ./Main.1
```

on the command line in the directory where "Main.1" is located.

If you run

```
xcodebuild install
```

on the command line then the manual page is copied to the

```
$DSTROOT/usr/share/man/man1/
```

directory, where `DSTROOT` is the "Installation Build Products Location". The file is not used otherwise in the build process.

If you don't need a man page, you can just remove the file from the Xcode project.