# No Header File in XCode 5... Replaced with .1 file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

I haven't used X Code in a while, and upon opening some of my old projects, I find that I no longer have header files, and they have been replaced with a .1 file.

Is there something I'm missing? The .1 file itself is just an image preview...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'll attach images of what I'm seeing.

[image: This is the file structure]

[image: This is the image that opens]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you use command line utility tool in Xcode?

Comment: I did. This is an older project that I created when learning objective-c, but all of my older works are in this same fashion. Some have a .pch file, but none of my @interface methods are shown in those files.

Comment: are files available in your project directory? i mean, use finder to find them.

Comment: The folder containing all projects is located on my Desktop. The .h files are not found in the folder, nor when I search with finder...

Comment: where is the actual .xcodeproj file located? is it in desktop or ?

Comment: i think, you accidentally deleted those files from your desktop.

Comment: It's in Desktop>XCode Projects>BeerSong

Comment: When creating a new project, I have TheProject.m and TheProject.1 in the package explorer. Along with TheProject.pch in a subfolder "Supporting Files"... Is this something to do with the latest xCode update and sdk?

Comment: creating Xcode project via command line or Xcode->File->New->project ?

Comment: Creating from Xcode>File>New Project or the New Project screen on program start.

Comment: oh.. what type of project are you going to create? is it any console app or OSX or iOS?

Comment: Creating a new iOS app gives me AppDelegate.h & .m Main Storyboards, and ViewController.h & .m files

Comment: aha,, is that you need?

Comment: Well, I was going to work through a new objective C book I got and the book requires me to create some command line projects, so I was hoping to return the functionality to normal

Comment: so start writing the code inside the main file .  
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}

Comment: Where would I put the @interface methods?

Comment: The .1 file is a "man page", compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459869/what-does-main-1-output-file-do-in-xcode.

Comment: this will help you,,, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/RM_YourFirstApp_Mac/Articles/GettingStarted.html'

Comment: The second link won't allow me to open it

Comment: So, @MartinR am I correct in reading that I can just delete the .1 file?

Comment: @ChrisHooked: Yes. But I wonder that that the file is displayed as an icon. It should be a plain text file, starting with `.\"Modified from man(1) of FreeBSD, the NetBSD mdoc.template, and mdoc.samples.`. - Perhaps you have an application on your computer that uses the .1 file extension.

Comment: I think Entropy opened once when I clicked the file, but I have since removed the application

Comment: Any idea what other application would interfere with xCode like that?

Comment: @ChrisHooked: Locate the file in the Finder and choose "Get Info" or "Open With …".

Comment: @ChrisHooked: Is your question about opening an old project in Xcode 5, or about creating a new project (for an Objective-C command-line tool) ?

Comment: I've tried to find the file and choose "Open With" and none of the programs seem out of the ordinary to me... The problem is in both creating a new project and opening an existing project

Comment: @ChrisHooked: If you create a new project then you can just delete or ignore the .1 file. - I cannot imagine that Xcode removes header files or creates new files when you open an existing old project, so that is unclear to me. Do the header files (from the old project) exist in the file system? Are they just missing in the Xcode project?

Comment: They are non existent in the file system, and there is no header file created upon creating a new xcode project

Comment: There was never a class and therefor no header in this project. Compile it. If it compiles nothing is missing.

Comment: It runs, but what happened to the methods I defined? They are nowhere to be seen.

Comment: There was definitely a header at one point